# Using Column value as foldername when exporting images MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

When exporting images using MSSQL, is there a way to specify a columns value as a new folder name?

For example, I have a field called ReportID that I would like a folder to be created inside my already created "images" folder if it doesn't already exist, (multiple records could hold the same ReportID).

My script is as follows: (the correct file path is being written, but no images are being saved, and I assume it's not creating folders properly)

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO

DECLARE @file int,
    @FilePath varchar(80),
    @hr INT,
    @FK_ReferenceID INT,
    @FK_FieldID INT,
    @Value VARBINARY(MAX),
    @Extension varchar(4),
    @ReportID INT;
DECLARE imgs CURSOR 
FOR SELECT FK_ReferenceID, FK_FieldID, Value, Extension, ReportID FROM     dbo.ImageValues
FOR UPDATE OF FilePath;

OPEN imgs;  
FETCH NEXT FROM imgs INTO @FK_ReferenceID, @FK_FieldID, @Value, @Extension, @ReportID;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SELECT @FilePath = 'E:\Reports\images\' +  CAST(@ReportID AS VARCHAR(10)) + '\'  + CAST(@FK_ReferenceID AS VARCHAR(10)) + '-f' + CAST(@FK_FieldID AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.' + CAST(@Extension AS VARCHAR(4));

EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @file OUT;
EXEC sp_OASetProperty @file, 'Type', 1;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @file, 'Open';
EXEC sp_OAMethod @file, 'Write', NULL, @Value;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @file, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @FilePath, 2;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @file, 'Close';
EXEC sp_OADestroy @file;

UPDATE dbo.ImageValues SET FilePath = @FilePath WHERE CURRENT OF imgs;

FETCH NEXT FROM imgs INTO @FK_ReferenceID, @FK_FieldID, @Value, @Extension, @ReportID;
END
CLOSE imgs;
DEALLOCATE imgs;
GO

sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 0;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Comment: Could you show the data values you are working with? Also when you say the "correct file path is being written", do you mean the folder is being created? Could you show the folder structure being created, and also dump / echo your FilePath?

Comment: The script above will export IMAGE types to a file on the Server in folder E:\Reports\images\ (as well as name it a combination of the ReferenceID -f and fieldID) as well as write the path and the created file name to a column labeled FilePath.

I was hoping to use the ReportID column to generate a new folder name, if needed, (E:\Reports\images\<ReportID>\<ReferenceID-f<FieldID>,<extension>), and save the image in that folder.  However, the IMAGE is not being created on the server, however, the file path is being written back into the FilePath column.

Comment: I'm assuming the images aren't being created because the folders aren't being created because if I remove the option for creating the folder, the script works great.

So, I'm wondering if there is someway of having SQL check for and create a folder based on the value of a column?

Comment: One way to do this is to break this into 2 steps, (1) create the folders first anyways and (2) then the file. You would need to check for exceptions in both steps, in the first step you would ignore if the exception that folder already exists. Alternatively you could first check if the folder exists and then create it and then the file. As far as I know, SQL automatically would not do such checks for you.

Comment: The problem is there are over 6000 folders that would need to be created, so doing this manually would be extremely time consuming.  I'll search for just creating the folders first, as that may be my only option.  Thanks vmachan.

Comment: vmachan, I'm going to accept your answer.  I ran a vba script that created the folders in the directory, and then ran the script above and it appears the images are being placed in the right folder.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Unsure if you can provide points for a comment, since I did not put this in an answer. Maybe you can upvote the comment, Glad it helped!

Comment: I can't.  Can you submit it as an answer?

Comment: Submitted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to break this into 2 steps, (1) create the folders first anyways and (2) then the file. You would need to check for exceptions in both steps, in the first step you would ignore if the exception that folder already exists. Alternatively you could first check if the folder exists and then create it and then the file. As far as I know, SQL automatically would not do such checks for you.